# How do I use mongoexport to export all records in a collection to a CSV file

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I am trying to export data to a CSV file but for some reason I am not getting any data in the CSV file.

I have a DB called "test", and a collection called "people". The contents of the people collection is (json export works!):

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"55937ce0c64ddad5023a9570"},"name":"Joe Bloggs","position":"CE"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"55937d57c64ddad5023a9571"},"name":"Jane Bloggs","position":"CE"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"55937d62c64ddad5023a9572"},"name":"Peter Smith","position":"CE"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"55937d78c64ddad5023a9573"},"name":"Sarah Smith","position":"STL"}
```

I am trying to export this data into a CSV file with the following command:

```
mongoexport --type=csv -d test -c people --fieldFile c:\dev\peopleFields.txt --out c:\dev\people.csv
```

When I run this command, the response is:

```
2015-07-01T14:56:36.787+0800   connected to: localhost
2015-07-01T14:56:36.787+0800   exported 4 records
```

The contents of peopleFields.txt is:

```
ID
Name
Position
```

And the resulting output to the people.csv file is:

```
ID,Name,Position
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
"","",""
```

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is that the `--fieldFile` option is not a "mapping" but just a "list" of all the fields you want to export from the collection.

So to actually "match" fields present in your collection the content should be:

```
_id
name
position
```

Since the names you have do not match any fields, you get four lines ( one per document ) of blank field output, for the number of fields you specify.

The `mongoexport` utility itself will not "map" to alternate names. If you want different names to how they are stored in your collection then you will have to alter the output yourself.

The same goes for the output as any `ObjectId` value will be output as that literal string.

Comment: Ah ha! Case sensitivity, of course, it's JavaScript! Silly me to forget this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarkieB Not **just** "case sensitivity" but the names are in fact "different". So "ID" is not equal to "_id". The field names must be exactly the same in order to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command to export data in csv file:

```
mongoexport --db dbName --collection collectionName  --type=csv --fields name,position --out fileName.csv
```

As per [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/),

> 1) The `fieldFile` allows you to specify  fields to include in the export.
>
> 2) The file must have only one field per line, and the line(s) must end with the LF character (0x0A).

You are using different name (ID, Name, Position) in text file as that of in collection (_id, name, position)so you are getting empty fields exported.